# consulta eloquent con where and y orwhere

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Estoy tratando de verificar si existen registros dentro de un rango de fechas.
pero al parecer no esta funcionando.

Tengo una fecha inicial, una final y un campo proceso.
necesito verificar si un proceso se encuentra en ese rango de fechas.

Pero tienen que cumplirse alguna de las dos fechas, es decir:

Si existen registros entre el dia 6 y el dia 10 de un proceso, si yo consultara registros  del 4 al 7, este deberia traerme algunos registros, si yo consultara entre el 9 y el 12, este deberia traerme  algunos registros, si yo cosultara entre el 6 y el 10, este me trae todos los registros.

Si yo consultara del 3 al 5, o del 11 en adelante claramente no me deberia traer registros.

pero no me funciona:

```
$data = tabla1::where('fecha_inicial', '>=', $Finicial)
        ->orwhere('fecha_inicial', '<=', $Ffinal)
        ->where('fecha_fin', '<=', $Ffinal)
        ->orwhere('fecha_fin', '>=', $Finicial)
        ->where('proceso', $proc)
        ->get();
```

en esta consulta si yo consulto datos entre el 5 y el 9, no me trae datos, o si consulto entre el entre el 9 y el 12 tampoco me trae datos.

estuve viendo como interpreta mysql esta consulta y me muestra que esta asi:

```
 select * from `ciclos` where `fecha_inicial` >= ? or `fecha_inicial` <= ? and
 `fecha_fin` <= ? or `fecha_fin` >= ? and `proceso` = ?
```

Como podria hacer para que mi consuta funcione adecuadamente? muchas gracias.

Es decir, la consulta que busco seria algo como:

**(** la fechaInicialParametro  >= a fecha inicial Y la fechaInicialParametro <=  a la fecha final **)** O **(** la fechaFinalParametro sea <= fecha final Y fechaFinalParametro >= fecha inicial **)** Y proceso == ?

Es para validar que almenos una de las 2 fechas se encuentre en ese rango de fechas.

Comment: mm No entiendo la pregunta, puede ser cualquier orden, solo debo traer los registros si la fecha inicial se cumple o la fecha final se cumple.

Comment: Si creo que es lo que busco, pero no se como hacerlo, los opcionales serian  ( la fechaInicialParametro  >= a fecha inicial Y la fechaInicialParametro <=  a la fecha final) O ( la fechaFinalParametro sea <= fecha final Y fechaFinalParametro >= fecha inicial ) Y proceso == ?

Es para validar que almenos una de las 2 fechas se encuentre en ese rango de fechas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema inicial de tu consulta es que las condiciones a evaluar no están quedando agrupadas (*como es la intención según lo que expones en los comentarios*).

Entonces puedes construir tu query de esta forma:

```
tabla1::where([
          ['fecha_inicial', '>=', $Finicial],
          ['fecha_inicial', '<=', $Ffinal]
      ])->orWhere([
          ['fecha_fin', '<=', $Ffinal],
          ['fecha_fin', '>=', $Finicial]
      ])->where('proceso', $proc)
      ->get();
```

O de esta forma mediante el uso de closures:

```
tabla1::where(function ($query) use ($Finicial, $Ffinal){
    $query->where('fecha_inicial', '>=', $Finicial)
            ->where('fecha_inicial', '<=', $Ffinal);
})->orWhere(function ($otraQuery) use ($Ffinal, $Finicial){
    $otraQuery->where('fecha_fin', '<=', $Ffinal)
    ->where('fecha_fin', '>=', $Finicial);
})->where('proceso', $proc)->get();
```

En ambos casos lo que buscamos es conjuntar 2 grupos de condiciones y un *where* externo independiente a los anteriores, recomiendo leas [la doc. al respecto](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#basic-where-clauses)

Comment: Muchas gracias, por tu explicacion.